# using a div to blur an image behind it?

Tags: css, html, webkit, blur

Is it possible to code a div to enable it to blur whatever image is under it?

something like this:

[image]

Could this be done somehow with `-webkit` maybe?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Not with CSS on its own, but you can pull a similar effect off with Canvas and the StackBlurforCanvas library. See [this](http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript)

**UPDATE:** Looks like `backdrop-filter` was [recently introduced to Webkit nightly,](https://www.webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/) so eventually we'll be able to do this with CSS only. Yay!

Comment: For support of the `backdrop-filter` see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter

Comment: **it actually is possible with CSS alone** https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543010/7543162

Comment: `backdrop-filter` can now be used in all major browsers (August 2019)

Comment: @magikMaker it's not currently supported by Firefox, but they're working on it https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1178765

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this can't be done purely using CSS. Although webkit-filter supports blur, it doesn't support blurring anything other than the element that it applies to.

There is a more hacky way to do this, described here - http://css-tricks.com/blurry-background-effect/

Comment: Ow that's a shame, never mind! would of been a nice feature