# CSS: Workaround to backdrop-filter?

Tags: html, css

`backdrop-filter` is a recent CSS feature, that is not yet available in modern browsers (at least as of July 1, 2016).

- Chrome 51 supports `backdrop-filter` via Experimental Web Platform flag.
- Safari 9.1 supports it with `-webkit-` prefix
- Firefox 47 have no support

Being in such an unusable state, I would like to know whether there exists any alternative way to bring in the same result.

JS workarounds for `blur`, `grayscale`,… are also welcome

The development of `backdrop-filter` can be tracked through https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=497522

Comment: can you please elaborate by specifying exactly what you want?or explain the new feature

Comment: @SrikerCh blur, grayscale filters

Comment: star the issue in chrome bug tracker to get it sooner: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=497522

Comment: use another div to set background and the effect you need and use position and size same as the target element and apply filter, which won't affect the contents of target element

Comment: **TL;DR:** Use e.g. `filter: blur()` etc. instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of Chrome M76, backdrop-filter is now shipped, unprefixed, and without a needed flag.

https://web.dev/backdrop-filter/

NOTE: (since this answer keeps getting downvoted because Mozilla hasn’t yet shipped it): this feature is available in Safari, Chrome, and Edge, but not yet in Firefox. Mozilla is [planning](https://groups.google.com/g/mozilla.dev.platform/c/1MN77cE21fE/m/Fej_wGI7AQAJ) to ship it very soon, but hasn’t yet. So this answer doesn’t contain a “workaround” but simply more information about which browsers **require** a workaround. Which still seems like useful information.

Comment: Currently on Firefox 74 and still no support for `backdrop-filter`. Not everyone uses Chrome or a chromium-based browser, also, I downvoted this because this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Since the question was "workaround to backdrop-filter", I thought people might be interested in knowing that a workaround is not needed for Chrome. Firefox is in development for this feature, and it can be tried out today using the layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled flag.

Comment: @Bruno Finger Firefox support backdrop-filter but you need to change two options on about:config [check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

Comment: Well, it's late 2020 and Firefox still doesn't have it! Too bad it is still behind a couple flags, so yup...that's not the correct answer for a "workaround".

Comment: The main reason [I implemented backdrop-filter in Chromium](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/GRl1_Qy97jM?pli=1) was that there isn't a *real* workaround for this feature. Applying a filter to *just* the content behind an element, especially if either the backdrop content is moving (e.g. video) or the foreground element overlaps many separate elements, is practically impossible. Hence my desire to point out the state of the native implementations. I would guess many people come here looking for a workaround, get disappointed, and wonder when the feature will be available.

Comment: Thank you very much for your implementation work on Chromium. Please also understand that promoting your work to the people who are searching for a *workaround* might not always be appreciated. Some might even think that you are discouraging a fallback *because* the feature is now (soon) available on the current #1 browser. You, as a browser developer, are surely aware that history has proven how wrong this (supposed) principle is. TLDR; Even if all the major browsers support a new feature, telling so is still the wrong answer *to the question of a workaround*, even if the OP disagrees .

Comment: Thanks - I get that. I wasn't really trying to promote my work, just establish that I **do** have some context here. And I feel pretty strongly that there really isn't a "workaround" for backdrop filter. I see your answer below, which is helpful. But the "workaround" is just to use 0.9 alpha. But that only (mildly) approximates `backdrop-filter:blur()`. There's **no workaround possible** for something like this: https://codepen.io/robinrendle/full/LmzLEL. Do you not think people reading this question eventually wonder about native implementations? Sorry if the tone of my answer seems off.

Comment: Apple seems to have a workaround that works in Firefox: https://www.icloud.com/
You can see it on the start page even without an account. When you log in they even transition the amount of blur. I have not the time though at the moment to check how they did it.

Comment: Yep, the "workaround" there is to just apply a filter (not a backdrop-filter) to the entire blurred mock-springboard. Search the HTML for this element: `<div class="bootstrap-mock-springboard-view" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute;pointer-events: none;user-select: none;width: 412px;height: 575px;filter: blur(31.8667px);z-index: -1;left: 0px;top: 44px;">`. Notice the `blur(31.8667px)`. That workaround only works if you already know you want to blur the entire page, so it's not really much of a workaround. But I suppose it's something!

Comment: Mid-2021 and still not soon enough.

Comment: this is not a solution or workaround! late 2021!

Answer (score 154):

I use this to get the popular frosted glass effect. Until someone successfully invents a good polyfill for `backdrop-filter` I'm using a slightly transparent background as a fallback:

```
/* slightly transparent fallback */
.backdrop-blur {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

/* if backdrop support: very transparent and blurred */
@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: none) or (backdrop-filter: none)) {
  .backdrop-blur {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2em);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2em);
  }
}
```

The filter will work in [currently supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) browsers. (Safari and Chrome with experimental Web Platform features enabled) The code should also work in future browsers that support unprefixed `backdrop-filter` if the spec doesn't change before that.

Examples without and with backdrop-filter support:

[image: transparent fallback]
[image: blurred]

Comment: Of course [@support does not work in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-featurequeries) but it works in [all browsers that support backdrop-filter](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter) so the above fallback should work as intended.

Comment: I like this approach. One minor detail I learned today here https://blog.logrocket.com/new-in-chrome-76/ is that '@supports' can be used with e.g. 'none' in this case. The benefit is that the actual values aren't unnecessarily duplicated.

Comment: Thanks @akauppi that's cleaner indeed. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 95):

**Update as of 5/01/22:**

[Backdrop Filter](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/#:%7E:text=The%20backdrop-filter%20property%20in%20CSS%20is%20used%20to,background%20and%20instead%20of%20to%20the%20element%E2%80%99s%20content.) has received further support, check the link for the versions of each browser that support it and a quick tutorial.

**Syntax:**

```
.element {
            backdrop-filter: <filter-function> [<filter-function>]* | none
         }
```

---

**Older Solution**

I don't know if you're still chasing this question, but for other users in future:

This effect can be accomplished as follows with CSS Pseudo-Classes, no JavaScript is necessary!
shown below:

```css
body,
main::before {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/80625/tree.jpg) 0 / cover fixed;
}

main {
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .3);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  box-shadow: 5px 3px 30px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main::before {
  content: '';
  margin: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(20px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <blockquote>"The more often we see the things around us &#45; even the beautiful and wonderful things &#45; the more they become invisible to us. That is why we often take for granted the beauty of this world: the flowers, the trees, the birds, the clouds &#45;
    even those we love. Because we see things so often, we see them less and less."
    <footer>&mdash;
      <cite>
        Joseph B. Wirthlin
      </cite>
    </footer>
  </blockquote>
</main>
```

Live example can be seen on Codepen: https://codepen.io/jonitrythall/pen/GJQBOp

**Quick Note:**

Depending on the structure of your HTML document, ***your*** z-indexes may be different to the one described in the example.

Comment: Good workaround. But has a fallback because other elements over the background won't be blurred.

Comment: The only issue with this is that it's not dynamic of course. It's tied to a static image. But good workaround for that specific case :)

Comment: As I understand, the :before pseudoclass gets the same background-image as body on which we just use `filter: blur(2px);` So this trick won't work for other elements in the background.

Comment: i knew this would be possible with javascript. u dont know how many ppl on SO r going around telling ppl this isnt possible unless u use JS

Comment: is there any way to do this while using `main { width: calc(100% - 48px); max-width: 500px; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }`? i cant seem to get it to work :/ if i apply `transform: translate(50%, 50%)` to the blurred pseudo element, the blurred image matches the actual image, but the position of the blurred part is misaligned.

Comment: [heres a codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/gyYRoZ) of where im at, and what ive tried doing to try and fix this so far. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: nm. i figured it out. i can use and manipulate the `top` and `left` values of the card itself without using a `transform` on the card, as opposed to trying to manually position the pseudo element instead.

Comment: The before is not that relevant, what this answer shows is you can simply do a filter in the background elements, regardless of what those are (everything but the element you would apply the backdrop-filter to)

Answer (score 14):

Use SVG filters. <strike>They work like a charm.</strike> Checkout this example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/FbBdy).

`backdrop-filter` is now supported by default in Chrome Canary. It's also in the 2019 priority list for Firefox development. So, it will soon be supported across all browsers, but for now you can use SVG filters.

#### Update

SVG filters don't work exactly like `backdrop-filter`. It's only a workaround and it doesn't work if there's moving elements beneath it. Anyway, I think we're going to be able to use `backdrop-filter` in production very soon. It's now enabled by default in Chrome Beta! Which also means Edge.

Comment: Whilst links to external sources to back up your answer is very much encouraged, we discourage "link-only" answers as they are rendered useless if the link expires. Please update your answer to include the full solution.

Comment: Sounds great. Interesting use of SVG filters.

Comment: "very soon" ^^ It's been too years and FF haven't released it to prod yet 

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good solution to wokraround backdrop-filter, but not the same:

you can use it with @supports css rule

```
@supports not (backdrop-filter: blur(4px)) {
    body > *:not(#element) {
        filter: blur(4px);
    }
}
```

```css
body > *:not(#element) { /* select every child element in body but not the specified one*/
    background: #9fe2ff;
    filter: blur(4px);
}
#element {
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:10%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index:10;
}
div, p {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>div element with some text</div>
    <p>paragraph with another text</p>
    <div id="element">Not blured element</div>
    <div>Another div with blured text</div>
    <p>another p </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add specific workaround that works for me, maybe it's useful for someone out there.

The idea is to wrap every element that should be behind the popup into `.blurred` and make it blur with  `filter: blur(10px);` (which has better browser support) to it, but then the popup element itself should be outside `.blurred`.

in code it looks like this:

```css
.blurred {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    filter: blur(4px);
}

.popup {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.popup__box {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
 }
```

```html
<div class="blurred">
  <div>Maybe a navbar goes here</div>
  <h3>Hi, I'm blurred</h3>
  <img src="https://filesamples.com/samples/image/jpg/sample_640%C3%97426.jpg" alt="sample"/>
  <div>Maybe a footer goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__box">
    Hi, I'm a popup
  </div>
</div>
```

The downside to this workaround is that you have to wrap everything inside the `.blurred` class, which can be hard (at least for me) sometimes to manage the z-index with other element outside.

Answer (score 2):

As explained on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) changing the value of the preference `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` from `false` to `true`  on the `about:config` page seems to work for me.

I'm using Firefox Developer 87.0b1 (64 bits)

Comment: I think it's necessary to enable `gfx.webrender.all` too... or does it work with only that? Anyway, it won't work on a prod app because you can't ask your customers to enable these features on their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add different filters to the background images:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

The downfall to this, is that it only works on images.

Basically, there are 10 built-in filters for the CSS `filter` property:

- blur(px)
- brightness(%)
- contrast(%)
- drop-shadow(h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color)
- grayscale(%)
- hue-rotate(deg)
- invert(%)
- opacity(%)
- saturate(%)
- sepia(%)

And additionally, you can provide it an url, wich contains an XML file with the appropariate filter.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to check the availability of backdrop-filter within Javascript you can use:

```
CSS.supports("backdrop-filter", "blur(10px)")
```

In a condition:

```
if (CSS.supports("backdrop-filter", "blur(10px)")) {
     // some code when supported
} else {
     // some code when not supported
}
```

This works not for Internet Explorer so if there is a fallback it's better.

Answer (score 0):

All desktop browsers appear to now support drop-filter. However, the most recent Firefox for android still does not by default (https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter). I use this approach for mobile Firefox and older browsers, in this example, I am using Bootstrap variables, (https://www.thiscodeworks.com/firefox-css-backdrop-filter-workaround-css/60facccc0c27230014227666):

```
/* Slightly transparent. Fallback to .9 (undefined --bs-bg-opacity) */
    .backdrop-blur {
    background-color: rgba(var(--bs-dark-rgb), var(--bs-bg-opacity, .9));
    }
     
/* if backdrop support, very transparent and blurred. --bs-bg-opacity set to .5 */
    @supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(20px))) {
      .backdrop-blur {
       --bs-bg-opacity: .5;
       -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
       backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
      }
    }
```