# Issue with backdrop-filter

Tags: html, css

Ihave an issue with the `backdrop-filter` property, because the filter i added in my backdrop-filter do nothing and i don't understand why.

Here is my code :

```css
.army_selection
    {
     margin: 20px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    
     min-width: 300px;
     max-width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
    
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    
     transition: 0.1s;
    }
    
    .army_selection:hover :nth-child(1)
    {
     opacity: 1;
    
     -webkit-backdrop-filter: brightness(25%);
    
     transition: 0.1s;
    }
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="army_selection">
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
    <p class="army_text">Ultramarines</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't state a background anywhere. Plus 25% brightness is quite small so you may not be noticing it. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VBxmqX

Comment: @Code_Ninja `filter` is not equivalent to `backdrop-filter`.

Comment: yes then I started reading more about these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That property is experimental and has limited support.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

To use in Chrome v.47 you need to `Enable Experimental Web Platform Features`.

Consider carefully the limited support; it is possible to achieve the same effect without this specific property. An example [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145368/css-workaround-to-backdrop-filter).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to accomplish something like this?

Here's a workaround, maybe it's not what you are looking for, hope it helps

```css
.army_selection {
     margin: 20px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    
     min-width: 300px;
     max-width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    
     transition: background-color .2s;
}
    
.army_selection:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="army_selection">
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
    <p class="army_text">Ultramarines</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that .army_selection have an image as background not just a color

Comment: So you want only the image to go transparent and not the 'Ultramarines' text, right?

Comment: yeah that's it .. but not transparent just less bright

Answer (score 0):

```css
.army_selection {
     margin: 20px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     min-width: 300px;
     max-width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
      opacity:-2;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    
     transition: background-color .5s;
}
    
.army_selection:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0.8, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="amySelection">
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
    <p class="army_text">Ultramarines</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.armySelection {
     margin: 20px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    
     min-width: 300px;
     max-width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    
     transition: background-color .2s;
}
    
.armySelection:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it's maybe be not the cleanest one

HTML part :

```
<div class="army_selection_bloc">
    <div id="army1" class="army_selection"></div>
    <div class="army_text_bloc">
        <p class="army_text">Space marines</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css part :

```
.army_selection_bloc
{
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.army_selection
{
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    transition: 0.1s;
}

.army_selection_bloc:hover .army_selection
{
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 60px black;

    filter: brightness(25%);

    transition: 0.1s;
}

.army_selection_bloc:hover .army_text_bloc
{
    opacity: 1;

    transition: 0.2s;
}


.army_text_bloc
{
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;

    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    opacity: 0;

    transition: 0.2s;
}
```