# The backdrop filter css has some margin in Safari

Tags: html, css

everyone.
I have one doubt about the backdrop CSS filter. It works on Chrome perfectly, but it has some margin on Safari.

```
background: transparent;
backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
--webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried hard reloading it on safari?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145368/css-workaround-to-backdrop-filter

Comment: Thanks for reaching me, Khushi. I have tried hard reloading, but it's the same.