# Backdrop Filter is not applied in CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to make a glassmorphism effect and my problem is that the webkit backdrop filter is not applied to the background of the div.
the css code:

```
.glassmorphism {
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.20);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10em);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10em);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}
```

html:

```
<div id="content__body" class="glassmorphism"></div>
```

And I get this error in chrome:
[invalid property value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4zIo.png)

Edit;
I just found out the problem myself:
I had two glassmorphism divs over eachother. For some reason that lead to a cancelation of the effect. In short: The styling above works but not for stacked divs

Comment: That's because the `backdrop-filter` is applied. Which is the unprefixed version. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145368/css-workaround-to-backdrop-filter

Answer (score 0):

Use **10px** instead of **10em**

and your backdrop filter is working.

Comment: Sorry nope that wasn't the problem