# How do I apply a style to a div but not the ones it contains

Tags: html, css, styles, styling

I have a form and some text inside a div that drops down from the top when you hover around it, what I want to do is make it so that when it drops, it makes everything behind it blurry and a bit darker, I've managed to do the darker part with

```css
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05)
```

but now I don't know how to make it blurry without making the form and text blurry as well.

(I want to make the nameInsert id div have the blurry background)

This is my html:

```html
<div id="nameInsert" class="nameInsert"> 
    <div id="nameList" class="nameList">
        <div id="boyNameList" class="boyNameList"></div>
        <div id="girlNameList" class="girlNameList"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="addNames" style="display: table-row;">
        <!-- DIVS WITH STYLES USED TO PLACE THEM SIDE BY SIDE -->
        <div class="boyForm">
            <form onsubmit="addBoyName(); return false">
                <label for="boyName"></label>
                <input type="text" name="boyName" id="boyName" placeholder="add guy" required>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and this is my css:

```css
.nameInsert{
    background-color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.nameList{
    margin-left: 3vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}

.boyNameList{
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;

    font-family: 'mesloBold';
}
```

thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps this question can give some ideas about blurry backgrounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145368/css-workaround-to-backdrop-filter

Comment: @akrys yep that was what I needed, thanks, you may post it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

your HTML had not div close now I've done you can use blow my code I hope you wanted this style

```css
.nameInsert {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.nameList {
  margin-left: 3vw;
  margin-right: 3vw;
}

.boyNameList {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;

  font-family: 'mesloBold';
}
```

```html
<div id="nameInsert" class="nameInsert">
    <div id="nameList" class="nameList">
      <div id="boyNameList" class="boyNameList"></div>
      <div id="girlNameList" class="girlNameList"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="addNames" style="display: table-row;">
    <!-- DIVS WITH STYLES USED TO PLACE THEM SIDE BY SIDE -->
    <div class="boyForm">
      <form onsubmit="addBoyName(); return false">
        <label for="boyName"></label>
        <input type="text" name="boyName" id="boyName" placeholder="add guy" required>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah it's just a bit of the whole file its closed later

Comment: you can do positioning the div