# Card flip not showing back. Front stays visible when flipped

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a flip card to maximize space on a webpage. When I toggle the flipCard function, the card flips but doesn't show the back and the front remains visible but is mirrored. Does anyone know why this is happening? The front of the card will consist of headings and the back is a UL.

Thanks for any help and your time!

```js
const card = document.getElementById("card")

card.addEventListener("click", flipCard);

function flipCard() {
  card.classList.toggle("flipCard");
}
```

```css
.cards {
    background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.4),
    rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1));
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    z-index: 10;
    perspective: 1000px;
    width: 400px;
}


.card-front {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

.card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

.flipCard {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.b {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ul-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    font-size: 12px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 3px;
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.d {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 6;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.d li {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="card" class="cards d">
            <div class="card-front">
                <h1>
                    This is the front!
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-back ul-grid">
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">SM.PINKY</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $1.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $8.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $16</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">PINKY</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $1.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $8.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $16 </li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">FUZZY</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $2.00 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $11.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $22</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">HOPPER</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $2.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $14.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $28</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">SMALL</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $3.00 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $17.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $34</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">MEDIUM</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $3.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $20.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $40</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">LARGE</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $4.00 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $23.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $46</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">JUMBO</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $4.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $26.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $52</li>
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why but removing the `backdrop-filter` makes it work.

Please read more about this problem [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145368/css-workaround-to-backdrop-filter)

You can use `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);` as a work around,
I haveupdated the code...

```js
const card = document.getElementById("card")

card.addEventListener("click", flipCard);

function flipCard() {
  card.classList.toggle("flipCard");
}
```

```css
.cards {
    background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.4),
    rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1));
    /*backdrop-filter: blur(10px);*/
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    z-index: 10;
    perspective: 1000px;
    width: 400px;
}


.card-front {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

.card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

.flipCard {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.b {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ul-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    font-size: 12px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 3px;
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.d {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 6;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.d li {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="card" class="cards d">
            <div class="card-front">
                <h1>
                    This is the front!
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-back ul-grid">
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">SM.PINKY</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $1.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $8.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $16</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">PINKY</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $1.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $8.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $16 </li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">FUZZY</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $2.00 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $11.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $22</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">HOPPER</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $2.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $14.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $28</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">SMALL</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $3.00 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $17.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $34</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">MEDIUM</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $3.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $20.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $40</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">LARGE</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $4.00 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $23.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $46</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="text-secondary">JUMBO</span>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $4.50 </li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $26.50</li>
                <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $52</li>
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's it! I appreciate the link to the post regarding the issue!

Comment:  most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be 100% efficient but this does what you describe

```js
const card = document.getElementById("card")

card.addEventListener("click", flipCard);

function flipCard() {
  let cInner = card.querySelector('.card-flip-inner');
  let cfront = card.querySelector('.card-front');
  let cback = card.querySelector('.card-back');
  cInner.classList.toggle("flipped");
  cfront.classList.toggle("hidden-card");
  cback.classList.toggle("shown-card");
}
```

```css
.cards {
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.4), rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1));
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 10;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 400px;
}

.card-flip-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  /*transition: transform 0.8s;*/
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.flipCard {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.b {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ul-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  font-size: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 3px;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.d {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 6;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.d li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.shown-card {
  visibiiity: visible;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden-card {
  visibiiity: visible;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="card" class="cards d">
  <div class="card-flip-inner">
    <div class="card-front shown-card">
      <h1>
        This is the front!
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card-back ul-grid hidden-card">
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">SM.PINKY</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $1.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $8.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $16</li>
      </ul>
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">PINKY</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $1.50 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $8.50 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $16 </li>
      </ul>
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">FUZZY</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $2.00 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $11.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $22</li>
      </ul>
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">HOPPER</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $2.50 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $14.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $28</li>
      </ul>
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">SMALL</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $3.00 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $17.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $34</li>
      </ul>
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">MEDIUM</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $3.50 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $20.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $40</li>
      </ul>
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">LARGE</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $4.00 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $23.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $46</li>
      </ul>
      <ul><span class="text-secondary">JUMBO</span>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(1)</span> $4.50 </li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(6)</span> $26.50</li>
        <li><span class="text-alt">(12)</span> $52</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```